# How can i show the position of a circle following mouse in other divs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to find the position of a circle that's following the mouse in two boxes
and the position of the circle when it's out of them. In addition when it (the circle) goes to red box the circle color changes to black, when it goes to red box it's color changes to red and when it's over neither of them it's blue.

I have included the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeDIZ.png).

```js
window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  let x = e.clientX;
  let y = e.clientY;
  let mouse = "Mouse : " + x + " " + y;
  document.getElementById("mouseText").innerText = mouse;

  let circle = document.getElementById("circleText");
  let newX = e.clientX + 5;
  let newY = e.clientY + 5;
  let newCircle = "circle : " + newX + " " + newY;
  document.getElementById("circleText").innerText = newCircle;

  let circle2 = document.getElementById("circle");
  circle2.style.marginTop = `${newY}px`;
  circle2.style.marginLeft = `${newX}px`;
});

function onMousemove(e) {
  var m_posx = 0,
    m_posy = 0,
    e_posx = 0,
    e_posy = 0,
    obj = this;
  //get mouse position on document crossbrowser
  if (!e) {
    e = window.event;
  }
  if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
    m_posx = e.pageX;
    m_posy = e.pageY;
  } else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
    m_posx =
      e.clientX +
      document.body.scrollLeft +
      document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    m_posy =
      e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  }
  //get parent element position in document
  if (obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      e_posx += obj.offsetLeft;
      e_posy += obj.offsetTop;
    } while ((obj = obj.offsetParent));
  }
  // mouse position minus elm position is mouseposition relative to element:
  dbg.innerHTML =
    " X Position: " + (m_posx - e_posx) + " Y Position: " + (m_posy - e_posy);
}
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
}

#circle {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

#row {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 200px;
}

#blackShape {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 125px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  right: 180px;
}

#redCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
}

#redShape {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 125px;
  margin-right: 150px;
}

#blackCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouseText"></div>

<div id="circleText"></div>

<div id="circle"></div>

<div id="dbg"></div>

<div id="row">
  <div id="blackShape">
    <div id="redCircle"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="redShape">
    <div id="blackCircle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script adjusts the position and size of the elements and listens when the blue circle will fall in these areas. When it leaves the area, the color style returns to its original state.

**Example when the blue dot is in the region:**
*After resizing the "Run code snippet" screen, it may not work correctly. Please copy the code and try it.*

```js
var pos = 5;  //<-- Circle position
var csz = 15; //<-- Circle size
var c = document.getElementById('circle');

window.onload = window.onresize = elPositions;

function elPositions() {
    blc = document.getElementById('blackShape');
    blcH = blc.offsetHeight;
    blcW = blc.offsetWidth;
    blcT = blc.offsetTop;
    blcL = blc.offsetLeft;

    red = document.getElementById('redShape');
    redH = red.offsetHeight;
    redW = red.offsetWidth;
    redT = red.offsetTop;
    redL = red.offsetLeft;
}

function changeColor(y, x) {
    if (redT - pos < y && redT + redH - pos - csz > y && redL - pos < x && redL + redW - pos - csz > x) {
        c.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }
    else if (blcT - pos < y && blcT + blcH - pos - csz > y && blcL - pos < x && blcL + blcW - pos - csz > x) {
        c.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    else {
        c.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    let x = e.clientX;
    let y = e.clientY;
    let mouse = "Mouse : " + x + " " + y;
    document.getElementById("mouseText").innerText = mouse;

    let circle = document.getElementById("circleText");
    let newX = e.clientX + pos;
    let newY = e.clientY + pos;
    let newCircle = "circle : " + newX + " " + newY;
    document.getElementById("circleText").innerText = newCircle;

    let circle2 = document.getElementById("circle");

    circle2.style.marginTop = newY + 'px';

    circle2.style.marginLeft = newX + 'px';

    changeColor(newY, newX); //<-- New Line
});

function onMousemove(e) {
    var m_posx = 0,
        m_posy = 0,
        e_posx = 0,
        e_posy = 0,
        obj = this;

    //get mouse position on document crossbrowser
    if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
    }

    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
        m_posx = e.pageX;
        m_posy = e.pageY;
    }

    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
        m_posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        m_posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    //get parent element position in document
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            e_posx += obj.offsetLeft;
            e_posy += obj.offsetTop;
        }

        while ((obj = obj.offsetParent));
    }

    // mouse position minus elm position is mouseposition relative to element:
    dbg.innerHTML = " X Position: " + (m_posx - e_posx) + " Y Position: " + (m_posy - e_posy);
}
```

```css
html {
    position: relative;
}

#circle {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; /*<-- New Line*/
}

#row {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 200px;
}

#blackShape {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 125px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    right: 180px;
}


#redCircle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
}

#redShape {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 125px;
    margin-right: 150px;
}

#blackCircle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouseText"></div>
<div id="circleText"></div>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="dbg"></div>
<div id="row">
    <div id="blackShape">
        <div id="redCircle"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="redShape">
        <div id="blackCircle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Example when the mouse cursor is in the region:**

```js
document.getElementById('blackShape').addEventListener("mouseover", getColor);
document.getElementById('blackShape').addEventListener("mouseout", retColor);

document.getElementById('redShape').addEventListener("mouseover", getColor);
document.getElementById('redShape').addEventListener("mouseout", retColor);

function getColor() {
    var x = this.id;
    var c = document.getElementById('circle');
    if(x === 'redShape') {
        c.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
    }
    else if (x === 'blackShape') {
        c.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    }
}

function retColor() {
    var c = document.getElementById('circle');
    c.style.backgroundColor = '';
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    let x = e.clientX;
    let y = e.clientY;
    let mouse = "Mouse : " + x + " " + y;
    document.getElementById("mouseText").innerText = mouse;

    let circle = document.getElementById("circleText");
    let newX = e.clientX + 5;
    let newY = e.clientY + 5;
    let newCircle = "circle : " + newX + " " + newY;
    document.getElementById("circleText").innerText = newCircle;

    let circle2 = document.getElementById("circle");

    circle2.style.marginTop = newY + 'px';

    circle2.style.marginLeft = newX + 'px';
});

function onMousemove(e) {
    var m_posx = 0,
        m_posy = 0,
        e_posx = 0,
        e_posy = 0,
        obj = this;

    //get mouse position on document crossbrowser
    if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
    }

    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
        m_posx = e.pageX;
        m_posy = e.pageY;
    }

    else if (e.clientX || e.clientY) {
        m_posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        m_posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }

    //get parent element position in document
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            e_posx += obj.offsetLeft;
            e_posy += obj.offsetTop;
        }

        while ((obj = obj.offsetParent));
    }

    // mouse position minus elm position is mouseposition relative to element:
    dbg.innerHTML = " X Position: " + (m_posx - e_posx) + " Y Position: " + (m_posy - e_posy);
}
```

```css
html {
    position: relative;
}

#circle {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1; /*<-- New Line*/
}

#row {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 200px;
}

#blackShape {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: 125px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    right: 180px;
}


#redCircle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
}

#redShape {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 125px;
    margin-right: 150px;
}

#blackCircle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 45%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouseText"></div>
<div id="circleText"></div>
<div id="circle"></div>
<div id="dbg"></div>
<div id="row">
    <div id="blackShape">
        <div id="redCircle"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="redShape">
        <div id="blackCircle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful! :) If you wish, you can mark my answer as Accepted Answer and give it a positive vote